# Improving work with SQL DataTime

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

I have a business in my Date. I need change date below

for each date before 25 of each month I want get 25 of month before and for each date after 25 of each month I want get 25 of the same month.

Example :

for 2015/06/24 (or 2015/06/06) I need 2015/05/25

and for 2015/06/25 (or 2015/06/30) I need 2015/06/25

I write this query :

```
DECLARE @A DATE = '2015/06/01'


SELECT  
    ( CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(MONTH, DATEADD(Day, -25, @A), @A) = 0
           THEN DATEADD(DAY, 25, DATEADD(Day, -DAY(@A), @A))
           ELSE DATEADD(DAY, 25, DATEADD(MONTH, -1, DATEADD(Day, -DAY(@A), @A)))
      END )
```

But I am looking for better solution.

Comment: Tip: It is helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`. Differences in syntax and features often affect the answers (as noted by Amit).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
SELECT IIF(DAY(@A) >= 25,
           DATEADD(d, 25 - DAY(@A), @A),
           DATEADD(d, 25, EOMONTH(@A, -2)))
```

Here's a sample fiddle as well: [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/64352/4)

*Note: `EOMONTH` requires SQL Sever 2012 or above - it returns the End-Of-Month date given a start date and a month offset.*

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do it with a single dateadd statement:

```
SELECT dateadd(dd, 25 - datepart(dd, @A), @A)
```

Datepart gets the current day of the month ( 1 , 6, 30, whatever).

We subtract that out, then add in 25 to give the result you want, the 25th of the month.